# How to remove Oracle and Adobe updaters from autostart?

Tags: windows-7, boot, updates, automatic-update

Just because I *use* Java, Flash and the Acrobat Reader doesn't mean I want to be *nagged* about new updates every time I just want to do something actually productive... There are no registry keys like `Software\Windows\Current Version\Run` or the good old Autostart group in the start menu, so where is this actually stored and how can I stop it for good?

Comment: Your path to the run registry entry is wrong should be for 32-bit HKCU or HKLM Software\microsoft\windows\currentVersion\run or for 64 bit Software\wow6432node\microsoft\windows\currentVersion\run. But to ignore the confusion use autoruns. :)

Comment: @PhillipR. I realized that when I ran autoruns :-/ So it's definitely better to just use that tool instead of trying to memorized all these possibilites...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with Sysinternals Autoruns:

[MS TechNet Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

Comment: +1 the easiest way to stop those naughty autoruns. :)

Comment: perfect, the next task is [to find a replacement for the StartupMonitor](http://superuser.com/q/471425/35237)...