# Disable ability to add startup items in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a tool like StartupMonitor for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/471425/is-there-a-tool-like-startupmonitor-for-windows-7)

Note: This is not the question "How to disable startup items" because the simple answer is: "Use msconfig".

Now as for my question:
I recently am very annoyed that some programs add startup items to my PC without my knowledge after installation, I always have 2 programs which startup - Temperature monitor and the Catalyst Control Center Tray.

Now, sometimes I install something and it adds startup entries, how can I make sure that no startup entries can be added to windows anymore?

So what I would like to do:

-Disable adding scheduled tasks (even for administrator accounts, so programs installing from them can't add startup entries too)

-Disable adding startup entries to the registry (even for administrators, would changing the permissions in HKLM on the Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run to read only be enough?)

-Disable all other methods of startup in Windows 7 I don't know

-Set default startup of *NEW* installed services to "Start Manually" instead of/and block "Start Automaticly" and "Start Automaticly (Delayed)"

How can I accomplish this?

This is also a nice way to prevent most viruses fom running after machine reboot (if this can be accomplished).

I am using 7 Ultimate so I have group policy editor, if that could be used.

Comment: Install Spybot version 1.6.2, then update it, then disable all active features but "tea timer", tea timer will alert you to registry startup items being added or deleted and allow you to decide to keep the changes or not. It protects all critical parts of the registry....http://superuser.com/questions/471425/is-there-a-tool-like-startupmonitor-for-windows-7/471477#471477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not direct way of doing this. But you can try a workaround, you can have some script scheduled to run at Shutdown, and that script restores the registry entry to the previous state, a state which does not have unwanted registry entries. I have never tried it, but I think this should work.

Comment: genius idea, shows how stupid I am :p

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for cannot be done, because someone with administrative privileges can easily undo any restriction you apply. It's also not sensible, because you may seriously break software that requires a service to start automatically by forcing the service startup to "manual".

Basically, what you're asking is: "How can I protect a machine from its administrator?"

And the answer to this question is: "You can't."

Comment: I'm not asking "How can I protect a machine from its administrator?", Short example of what I thought for the registry run when making it read only: Program tries to add entry: can't be added because it's read only. Human tries to add entry: edit permissions, add entry, make read only again.

So no, I'm not asking how to protect the machine from the Administrator, I'm asking how to limit the use of administrator privilidges by programs.

Comment: @GamErix A program can edit the permissions just as well. Like it or not, your question *does* boil down to "how can I protect a machine from its administrator?"