# Prevent accidental running u-torrent, when connected to office vpn?

Tags: utorrent

Is there a way to prevent(or alert) accidental running utorrent, when connected to office vpn?
I mean, only one should be running at any time, either u-torrent or the vpn.

Comment: How do you accidentally run anything?

Comment: @Moab: Precisely what I was thinking! Kiran, care to specify your OS?

Comment: yeah, you don't run it.

Comment: One word: **Discipline?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the end result we're going for is that we don't want utorrent traffic to be going through the VPN. The VPN will have a specific IP address, which is definately not the same as your system's own IP address. Now, we're basically doing the [reverse of the instructions](http://swimminginthought.com/bind-utorrent-specific-ip-route-vpn-speed/) here

First find the ip address of your *physical* ethernet adaptor - `ipconfig` should give you that, and it would be a line reading `ethernet adaptor local area connection` or `wireless lan adaptor`

Go to Utorrent, advanced and set net.bind_ip and net.outgoing_ip to this IP address. If there's anything else you can set (maybe an option for incoming IP) do the same.

This should cause Utorrent not to listen or send things via the VPN, which should prevent you from 'accidentally' using the VPN for torrents.

Comment: Excellent way of solving the problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks Jouneyman!!

Answer (score 6):

- Press the windows key + r
- type "msconfig" and press enter
- go to the startup tab and uncheck utorrent
- or uninstall utorrent
- other than this, I can't possibly help you not run something

Comment: msconfig is no "accident", but +1 for the best answer possible given the information provided.

Comment: And if utorrent keeps adding itself to autostart, use [TeaTimer](http://superuser.com/a/471477/35237)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another possible solution to the list:

I have [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) setup, a 'Work' install of Windows, set to bridged networking.

The VPN software is run in the virtual PC, allowing a connection to BOTH work and personal internet at the same time on the same physical PC.

This allows torrenting, web surfing, music streaming, etc, on the main desktop without having it use work internet. There are also file organization, security, and psychological benifits from the separated desktops.